# Adding non-nullable static type to memoized components throws lint error, see example for clarity

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Example 1.

Non-nullable `someStaticProperty`, this will throw a lint error

```
import { NamedExoticComponent, memo } from "react";

type WithComponentId = { componentId: string };

type ScreenComponentStaticMembers = {
  someStaticProperty: string;
};

type AliasedType<P = {}> = NamedExoticComponent<P & WithComponentId> &
  ScreenComponentStaticMembers;

type MyComponentProps = {
  greeting: string;
};

const MyComponent: AliasedType<MyComponentProps> = memo(({ greeting }) => (
  <span>{greeting} there!</span>
));

MyComponent.someStaticProperty = "baz";
```

Example 2.

Optional `someStaticProperty`, this will work.

```
import { NamedExoticComponent, memo } from "react";

type WithComponentId = { componentId: string };

type ScreenComponentStaticMembers = {
  someStaticProperty?: string;
};

type AliasedType<P = {}> = NamedExoticComponent<P & WithComponentId> &
  ScreenComponentStaticMembers;

type MyComponentProps = {
  greeting: string;
};

const MyComponent: AliasedType<MyComponentProps> = memo(({ greeting }) => (
  <span>{greeting} there!</span>
));

MyComponent.someStaticProperty = "baz";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `AliasedType` to be intersection of `NamedExoticComponent<P & WithComponentId>` and `ScreenComponentStaticMembers` and this means, that `AliasedType` *must* contain props from both `NamedExoticComponent<P & WithComponentId>` and `ScreenComponentStaticMembers`. But when you are creating variable `MyComponent` of type `AliasedType` you only assign it the object of the type `NamedExoticComponent<P & WithComponentId>` making `someStaticProperty` to be `undefined`. You only assign value to `someStaticProperty` on the next line.

To make your code work, use `Object.assign` to construct an object of the type `AliasedType`. This can be done like this

```
const MyComponent: AliasedType<MyComponentProps> = Object.assign({}, 
  memo<MyComponentProps>(({ greeting }) => (
    <span>{greeting} there!</span>
  )),
  { someStaticProperty:"baz" }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I properly type it so that I don't need to use `Object.assign`?

Comment: I'm afraid that `Object.assign` is the only way to solve this issue. From [source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/797c5362a2fc43c130a0d80807b9caaa759cf372/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L295) you may see, that it produces intersection which is required in this case.